# Calculus with Differential Forms.

Tags: real-analysis, differential-forms

> Let $\varphi, \psi$ and $\theta$ the following forms in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$.
>   $$\begin{eqnarray*}
> \varphi & = & xdx - ydy,\\
> \psi&=&zdx\wedge dy + xdy\wedge dz,\\
> \theta & = & zdy.
> \end{eqnarray*}$$
>   Calculate $\varphi \wedge \psi$, $\theta\wedge\varphi\wedge\psi$, $d\varphi$, $d\psi$ and $d\theta$.

**My attempt.**

$\begin{eqnarray*}
\varphi \wedge \psi & = & (xdx - ydy)\wedge(zdx\wedge dy + xdy\wedge dz)\\
& = & xzdx\wedge dx\wedge dy + x^2dx \wedge dy\wedge dz - yzdy\wedge dx \wedge dy - yxdy \wedge dy \wedge dz\\
& = & x^2dx \wedge dy\wedge dz - (-1)yzdy \wedge dy \wedge dx\\
& = & x^2dx \wedge dy\wedge dz
\end{eqnarray*}$

---

$\begin{eqnarray*}
\theta \wedge \varphi \wedge \psi & = & zdy \wedge (x^2dx \wedge dy\wedge dz)\\
& = & zx^2dy\wedge dx \wedge dy\wedge dz\\
& = & (-1)zx^2 dx \wedge dy \wedge dy \wedge dz\\
& = & 0.
\end{eqnarray*}$

---

$\begin{eqnarray*}
d\varphi & = & dx \wedge dx - dy\wedge dy\\
& = & 0.
\end{eqnarray*}$

---

$\begin{eqnarray*}
d\psi & = & dz \wedge dx \wedge dy + dx \wedge dy \wedge dz\\
& = & (-1)^2 dx \wedge dy \wedge dz + dx \wedge dy \wedge dz\\
& = & 2dx \wedge dy \wedge dz
\end{eqnarray*}$

---

$\begin{eqnarray*}
d\theta & = & dz\wedge dy\\
& = & (-1)dy \wedge dz\\
& = & -dy \wedge dz
\end{eqnarray*}$

---

Is correct? Seems simples, but I'm not sure if I'm using correctly the properties.

Comment: I read all of them in detail and I think it is all correct.

Comment: @GReyes thank you!